# Android count number of threads for an app/process

Tags: android, multithreading, adb

I need to monitor the behaviour of my app and collect statistics about how threads are created/destroyed. I know DDMS has a thread view which shows this information live, but could  I get the same information through the command line? I want to create my own tool which will log this information and the process it.

Clarification:
What I am looking for is a command that I can pass via ADB, which will list the threads running under a process. This way, I can run the command at different points of time to get the status of all threads (number of threads & their names) over a period of time.

Comment: please be more specific about what you are trying to achieve. do you have some code to show? what have you tried?

Comment: I tried cat /proc/<PID>/status, and this gives me just the number of threads. I s there a better way through which I can get more details of the threads?

Answer (score 8):

There are a two ways you can do this.
Tried this on a Motorola Moto G on Ubuntu 12.10

1. You can list *all* the thread running on the device by using `top` (under ADB Shell).

   ```
   $ top -t
   PID   TID PR CPU% S     VSS     RSS PCY UID      Thread          Proc
   271   895  1   0% S  11120K   1892K     root     netd            /system/bin/netd
   272   272  0   0% S   1040K    200K     root     debuggerd       /system/bin/debuggerd
   274   274  2   0% S  63256K   7008K  fg system   surfaceflinger  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
   274   451  0   0% S  63256K   7008K  fg system   Binder_1        /system/bin/surfaceflinger
   ```

   So to get details for any *particular* process you can use `grep`

   ```
   $ top -t | grep com.whatsapp
   PID   TID   PR CPU% S     VSS     RSS PCY UID      Thread          Proc
   15210 15210  0   0% S 550076K  51180K  bg u0_a96   com.whatsapp    com.whatsapp
   15210 15214  0   0% S 550076K  51180K  bg u0_a96   GC              com.whatsapp
   15210 15215  0   0% S 550076K  51180K  bg u0_a96   Signal Catcher  com.whatsapp
   15210 15216  0   0% S 550076K  51180K  bg u0_a96   Compiler        com.whatsapp
   ```

   To run this on your host Machine just use

   ```
   $ adb shell top -t | grep com.whatsapp
   ```

   If `grep` is not supported, use [Busybox](http://www.busybox.net/).
2. If you are looking for *Static* view. You can also use `ps`.

   ```
   $ ps -p 15210 -t                                         
   USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS   PRIO  NICE  RTPRI SCHED   WCHAN    PC         NAME
   u0_a96   15210 275   549036 52136 20    0     0     0     ffffffff 00000000 S com.whatsapp
   u0_a96   15214 15210 549036 52136 20    0     0     0     ffffffff 00000000 S GC
   u0_a96   15215 15210 549036 52136 20    0     0     0     ffffffff 00000000 S Signal Catcher
   u0_a96   15216 15210 549036 52136 20    0     0     0     ffffffff 00000000 S Compiler
   ```

   Where `15210` is the PID for your process `com.whatsapp`

Hope this solves your issues, let me know if it works.

Answer (score 7):

In my limited knowledge, and with the chances that I may be totally wrong, have a look at:

```
public static Map<Thread,StackTraceElement[]> getAllStackTraces()
```

Docs: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getAllStackTraces()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getAllStackTraces%28%29)

> Returns a map of stack traces for all live threads. The map keys are
>   threads and each map value is an array of StackTraceElement that
>   represents the stack dump of the corresponding Thread. The returned
>   stack traces are in the format specified for the getStackTrace method.
>   The threads may be executing while this method is called. The stack
>   trace of each thread only represents a snapshot and each stack trace
>   may be obtained at different time. A zero-length array will be
>   returned in the map value if the virtual machine has no stack trace
>   information about a thread.

I hope that helped.