# get number of processes using adb

Tags: android, adb

I have a LG H810 device and I want to get the total number of processes that are currently running on the device using adb command.

I don't want to see the actual processes, I only want the total number of running processes.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691487/how-to-detect-running-app-using-adb-command

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24125397/android-count-number-of-threads-for-an-app-process

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for , to get Process Count!

```
adb shell ps r|wc
```

BTW: you might want wc to count lines, so wc -l in that case.

like :

```
adb shell ps r|wc -l
```